# Sharepoint 2013 Search not returning results (file share content source)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

I'm having a problem with my search that is not returning any results. What I've done so far:

- Created a File Share folder inside the SharePoint Server
- Created a new Content Source in the Search Service Application pointing to this folder
- Created a Enterprise Search Center and pointed it as the deafult search center
- Started a Full Crawl (which resulted with successful for all the files)
- Reseted the Index, Timer Services, SharePoint Administration, SharePoint Search Host Controller and Search Server 15, did a Full Crawl again, success for all files
- On ULS Viewer there is no error related to the problem

Did all above and the problem still occurs. I suppose it could be one of the following:

**- PoPAuthProvider**: This the authentication provider used to authenticate on the webapplication (thats the only one enabled), I guess this could be the problem as on the file share (inside the server) I can only set NTLM users to access that folder

**-Search Config**: This is my first time setting up a FileShare search thing, so I might have missed some steps

**-FileShare config**: This is also my first time setting up such a thing, so I could also have missed some steps or made some mistakes

Could anyone give me a help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the user that you are using the check the search results in SharePoint may not have permissions to the file share.  SharePoint will trim results based on permissions.  Check that the user is able to access the files outside of SharePoint using the file explorer.

Comment: The thing is, the user is NOT an AD account, these users comes from an external authentication provider (connected to an AD, but for SharePoint is like you are other user than the AD one). Going with the windows explorer using the same AD account I can access all the files/folders without trouble. The only problem is with searching inside SharePoint.